# Update a package and keep it from reverting to the original

Tags: r, package, ggplot2

I want to upgrade the package ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
packageDescription("ggplot2")["Version"]
> 0.8.3
```

But the current version is 0.8.7.

I tried update.packages(), which seemed to work OK.  But it still returned older version 0.8.3.

So I downloaded and installed the package source from Cran, which says 0.8.7 in the download page.
I then install it via the GUI menu in R.  It returns

```
** building package indices ...
* DONE (ggplot2)
```

I then run:

```
packageDescription("ggplot2")["Version"]
> 0.8.3
```

And still I have the older version!

I don't know why this is not working, what's more I had already come across this problem before and solved it (I can't remember exactly what) but now it has gone back to the older version!  What's the easiest way to keep packages like this updated automatically and not have them refer back to older packages?

Comment: what is your OS?  And what is returned when you enter Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")?

Answer (score 6):

What version of R are you using? CRAN binaries are only kept up-to-date for the latest R release (i.e. 2.10.1). If you have an older version of R and have the development tools installed, you can use `install.packages("ggplot2",type="source")`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do unloadNamespace('ggplot2')? and the library(ggplot2) and then check the version? Because, once you load a package, it stays in memory of R, even though you might have already installed a newer version of the package, R does not see, until you do the above.