# when to use factor() when plotting with ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When do you normally use `factor` to color/size encode variables in ggplot2 in R? Example:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=drat, colour=gear))
```

versus:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=drat, colour=factor(gear)))
```

Is the general rule to use `factor` when the variable being used to determine the shape/size/colour is discrete, and not continuous? Or is there another use of `factor` in this context? It seems like the first command can be made like the second with the right legend, even without `factor`. thanks.

*edit*: I get this when I use the `colour=gear`:
[image]

Comment: Yes, it depends on what you want to show. If you're inclined to convey a sense of gradation, you use a continuous variable, but if you want to show groups, you're safest bet is to convert to factor.

Comment: Use `factor` when you have numerically coded variables that in fact represent categories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue isn't the legend, it's the choice of colors. When it is not a factor, the points are different shades of the same hue:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=drat, colour=gear))
```

[image]

This communicates a continuum of points, and it's thus not ideal for a set of separate possibilities. (Indeed, once you get to five or six possibilities the colors can be hard to distinguish from each other).

When `gears` *is* treated like a factor, the colors are chosen to be distinguishable:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=drat, colour=factor(gear)))
```

[image]

Note that if you're not getting a gradient plot when not using `factor`, you should try upgrading to a more recent version of `ggplot2`.

Comment: How do you get your first plot? I don't get a gradient legend when I just use `colour=gear`.

Comment: @user248237: I posted my code above each figure- I believe it is exactly the same as yours. Is it possible that in your data frame (version of R?), `gear` is already a factor? What do you get from `class(mtcars$gear)`?

Comment: I get `class(mtcars$gear) [1] "numeric"` when I type what you wrote. I am using RStudio.

Comment: @user248237: Same here, and in that case it's surprising it doesn't give a gradient. What version of ggplot are you using?

Comment: @user248237: Could you post the output of `sessionInfo` (which will include the version of `ggplot2`)?

Comment: I use `Package ggplot2 version 0.8.9`

Comment: Note that only recently ggplot2 started to support colorgradient legends, the ggplot2 version might very well be the problem. 0.9.0 also has the problem. 0.9.3 (most recent) does work as expected.

Comment: I used this to upgrade and the problem persists `> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package(s) into ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.12/ggplot2_0.8.9.tgz'`

Comment: @user248237: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656529/r-how-to-update-a-package-and-keep-it-from-reverting-to-the-original). It is likely that that is the latest version of ggplot for your version of R. As noted in the answer, you could try `install.packages("ggplot2",type="source")` if you have dev tools installed