# How to set color parameter in R when ploting an edcf?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working in R and I try to plot an *edcf* using *ggplot*.
To begin with, I have a table with 3 columns

```
 A | B | C  
 1  23  1  
 1  23  15  
 1  23  10  
 1  23  150   
 2  40  0  
 2  40  100  
 2  40  55   
 3  33  2
```

My goal is to plot an `edcf`, where for each value from B there would be a separate line and values are the ones from C.
Code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(C)) + stat_ecdf(aes(color="B"), geom='step')
```

I do get a cdf of the data but they are all summed in one line, something that I wasn't expecting after setting **color="B"**. Do you have any idea what my mistake is ?
**UPDATE:**
The following image is an example of something similar from what I would like to get. As you can see here there are two lines a red and a blue one, I am hoping to get (according to the table I have given here) 3 lines, one for B=23, another for B=40 and the third one for B = 33
[image]

Comment: Could you show a sample of your expected plot?

Comment: I have just updated it

Comment: Easier to understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  mutate(B=as.factor(B)) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(C)) + stat_ecdf(aes(color=B), geom='step')
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Can I ask you why my way of coding was wrong ? I saw it somewhere online as an example and it wondered me why isn't it working...

Comment: I think the issue is that using B as numeric will let it be treated as single points. A detailed explanation is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070738/when-to-use-factor-when-plotting-with-ggplot-in-r). Summary is the comment by Andrie on that post.